# Providing code hints/tags in C++ structs like in Golang

Tags: c++, go, reflection

In Golang I can write:

```
type Person struct {
    Id int `json:"id"`
}
```

Then on `JSON.Marshal(Person{})`, I get `{"id": 0}`. That is possible due to the `json` tag related to the `Id` field. Furthermore, I can provide any custom information in the tag section and treat it later using reflect on the struct.

Is there some analogy in C++, where I can provide additional info for a field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. C++ does not have any serialization support in the language. You have to write it with code or you can use third party tools and libraries like Cereal, Boost.Serialization, FlatBuffers, ThorSerializer, Cap'n Proto and so on for it.